# Selenium-Python ActionChain

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to mimic user behaviour in the browser, i want to paste text from clipboard to a form using ctrl+v from context menu not from keyboard.The code i am using to do this is:

```
driver.get('http://wikipedia.org')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput').perform()
```

This should open copy/paste/cut/undo dropdown menu but it never does regardless of the element at which i am right-clicking; i tried clicking on 'body' tag neither did that work. Keys and clicks are being performed via actionchains but why is context_click not showing the menu? Also i tried multiple chaining (sequence of actions) and a pattern of down,down,down,down after right click to paste the text in clipboard. No success. Help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: While we don't see the code to `paste text from clipboard to a form using ctrl+v from context menu` but still your code won't compile as you are missing a `)` at the fag end of the last line.

Comment: consider that it already is in clipboard ie; whatever is in clipboard should be pasted; the whole point is why wont context menu open, missing ')' was a mistake here